# Install Ceiling Fan Box with light only

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

Is it possible to install a ceiling fan box (new construction) and only attach a ceiling light fixture to it instead of a fan? I would like to have the fan box installed for future application but do not want a fan installed as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's a good idea. It's essentially the same box just stronger. It also needs to be installed with the correct hardware.  Install a fan box in every room where you would typically put in a ceiling fan, the cost to do it now is minimal compared to the cost of doing it later.

Comment: That's what I figured, we are building a new house and wanted to try to "future-proof' things as much as possible and it's easier to install some of these things during construction then afterwards. Thanks for the feedback!